# Request.getAttribute me devuelve valores null

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets, session, glassfish

Estoy armando un logueo. Tengo el formulario(login.jsp) que toma los datos por Post y me los manda al servlet(LoginServlet.java).
Los valido y los mando a otro servlet(header.jsp). Hasta acá el valor llega, lo comprobe imprimiendo en consola el valor. El problema es que cuando seteo el atributo y lo recibo en la JSP pasa como `NULL`.

Código de LoginServlet

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if(username.equals("ger") && pass.equals("1234")){

        session.setAttribute("user", "tu mama");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("/comic").forward(request, response);

    }else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

HeaderServlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    request.setAttribute("user", session.getAttribute("user"));

    request.getRequestDispatcher("header.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

header.jsp

```
<% String user = (String) request.getAttribute("user");%>
<%@page import="com.mycompany.webcomics.model.entities.User"%>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
        <a href="comic" class="navbar-brand"> <%=user%> </a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
   version="4.0">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mira si esto te funciona.

```
public String myMethod(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("midata", 'Hello World');

    return "home";//home.jsp
}
```

home.jsp

```
${midata}
```

Si no te funciona Model usa ModelAndView.

En vez de `request.setAttribute("user", session.getAttribute("user"));` usa el que pongo ahí, en el método `processRequest` pon un parametro ModelAndView:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView model)
```

y entonces ya podrás usar `model` y pasar atributos a la vista.